# Using nth-child in Scrapy

Tags: python, css-selectors, scrapy

I'm trying to extract some html using the Python tool Scrapy.

My selector is as follows:

```
#navigation > nav > div.js-accordion-menu-wrapper > ul li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10) > a::attr(href)
```

For some reason this isn't working at all.  Specifically, it seems that 'nth-child(-n + x) just doesn't work. Like maybe Scrapy doesn't use it or allow it.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: What version of `cssselect` do you have installed? (this is the package used in Scrapy to translate CSS selectors into XPath expression). [Version 1.0.0](https://pythonhosted.org/cssselect/#version-1-0-0) has a fix for `:nth-child(an+b)` with negative a's. Also, can you provide sample HTML with expected data you need to grab with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrapy 1.2.1 with cssselect 1.0.0 seems to be working as expected.

Here's a sample `scrapy shell` session:

```
In [1]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<ul>
   ...:     <li>1</li>
   ...:     <li>2</li>
   ...:     <li>3</li>
   ...:     <li>4</li>
   ...:     <li>5</li>
   ...:     <li>6</li>
   ...:     <li>7</li>
   ...:     <li>8</li>
   ...:     <li>9</li>
   ...:     <li>10</li>
   ...:     <li>11</li>
   ...:     <li>12</li>
   ...: </ul>""")

In [2]: selector.css('ul li:nth-child(n+5)').extract()
Out[2]: 
['<li>5</li>',
 '<li>6</li>',
 '<li>7</li>',
 '<li>8</li>',
 '<li>9</li>',
 '<li>10</li>',
 '<li>11</li>',
 '<li>12</li>']

In [3]: selector.css('ul li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10)').extract()
Out[3]: 
['<li>5</li>',
 '<li>6</li>',
 '<li>7</li>',
 '<li>8</li>',
 '<li>9</li>',
 '<li>10</li>']
```

I'm using:

```
$ scrapy version -v
Scrapy    : 1.2.1
lxml      : 3.6.4.0
libxml2   : 2.9.4
Twisted   : 16.5.0
Python    : 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38) - [GCC 5.2.1 20151010]
pyOpenSSL : 16.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)
Platform  : Linux-4.4.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial

$ pip freeze | grep cssselect
cssselect==1.0.0
```